# What is ideal configuration for Mysqld.cnf?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I run a news & media blog with over a few million readers every month. I'm currently using Google Cloud with a 32gb ram server with WordPress.

My server is hitting **84% memory usage** due to the following:

`usr/sbin/mysqld 20--daemonize 20--pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

If I were to restart the MySQL server it'd be okay for some time around 20% usage and it'll go up again to 80%. I'm unable to pinpoint the cause.

edit: corrected CPU to Memory.

Comment: Why is the CPU utilisation bothering you?

Comment: Sorry about that, I mistakenly added CPU instead of memory usage.

Comment: Msybe its just caching

Comment: It started only 3-4 days ago. Before it was fine, I tried looking up issue, but can't really find anything. and when it goes up to 80% memory usage, it says that much until I restart the MySQL server manually.

Comment: I can't mark it as a duplicate, but maybe this will help[MySQL maximum memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178736/mysql-maximum-memory-usage)

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out :)

Answer (score 0):

> hitting 84% memory usage

Good.

In General, MySQL is optimally configured "out of the box" these days.  Furthermore, cloud providers make sure it is well configured.

> restart ... around 20% usage

Good.  The main memory user, InnoDB's buffer_pool, grows over time, up to the limit of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Comment: I end up finding the issue, it was Smush Plugin that was increasing the load for some, I absolutely have no idea why.